# How to create an easy to explain regression model in Python with categorical features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

I have a dataset that looks like this, where each row is a user.

```
gender   age_group c1  c2     c3    total_cost
F        0-10      10  F1234  3456  135.2
F        65-100    10  G5143  876   523.6
M        18-35     15  F3457  876   98.5
F        0-10      10  F1234  545   1052.1
M        35-65     20  G5143  3456  345.8
```

What I need is to provide a model/summary of what factors contribute to the variance of `total_cost` by each combination of age_group and gender. This has to be done in python and explainability of each feature's contribution in each model is key.

`c1, c2 and c3` are the features of the model and are categorical (not numeric) and can have ~1000 different categories.

My initial thinking was to create a `Decision Tree` that will aid with the goal of it being more explainable, but the `DecisionTreeRegressor` scikit does not seem to support categorical variables. One-hot encoding could work, but with the potential of 1000s of categories for some features this does not seem to help with explanability at all.

What are my options for a more explainable model? Also, since I need to create different models for each combination of gender and age_group, what's a good way of doing that? The final model should be able to choose the appropriate model automatically for a given gender and age_group.

Comment: You can use [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to feed the tree with categorical values, you don't have to use one-hot vectors, But Categorical, or Label Encoded its going to give you as many features as one-hot encoding (equally hard to read, analyze either way). You may also want to check [f_regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html) from scikit-learn or [ELI5 library](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5) for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If one-hot-encoding doesn't help with explanability, it is probably because there are too many categories for the number of observations with some categories that probably rarely occur. I know this is probably self-evident but it would suggest using a dimensionality-reduction algorithm such as PCA.

Convert your `c1` feature (and subsequently all the other features) with one-hot-encoding and run [Multiple Correspondence Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis). It is essentially PCA for categorical features. Python implementation is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mca/1.0.2).